# ¿Se utiliza "provecho" en otros países hispanohablantes además de México?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, méxico, hispanoamérica

En México solemos decir "provecho" cuando despedimos a alguien cuando va a comer o para saludar cuando está comiendo.

¿Es esto un uso y costumbre solo de México, o también se utiliza en otros países?

Comment: He escuchado esa palabra en México y España.

Comment: Mike, ¿te criaste en el D.F. u otro gran centro urbano?  Yo he oído "provecho" a secas de vez en cuando pero más he oído "buen provecho" (en provincia).  // Hay una situación más en que se usa: Si A sirve la comida a B, A dice, "buen provecho."  Como decir "bon apétit."  Creo que ese uso es levemente diferente de lo que describiste.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uno de los significados que mencionas (respecto a las comidas) debería ser entendido en teoría por cualquier país hispanohablante, ya que el DLE no indica que sea un regionalismo, y asumiendo que se trata de una forma corta de la expresión "buen provecho".

[**buen provecho**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UTTXzlC)

> 1. *expr. coloq. U*. para manifestar el deseo de que algo sea útil o conveniente a la salud o bienestar de alguien, frecuentemente dirigiéndose a quienes están comiendo o bebiendo.

Y dicha expresión se puede encontrar desde hace varios años en la literatura:

> No digo tal -dijo Loaysa-, ni Dios tal permita. Bebed, hijo Luis, bebed, y buen provecho os haga, que el vino que se bebe con medida jamás fue causa de daño alguno.
>
> <sub>Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, El celoso extremeño, 1613</sub>

Ahora, que se use "provecho" para despedirse de alguien nunca lo he escuchado en Colombia. Ya tocaría ver que dicen otras respuestas en otros países.

Comment: No creo necesario añadir más; sobre lo último, diría que *(buen) provecho* en Argentina a veces se usa para despedirse, de la misma manera que a veces se usa *buen día* al despedirse, en lugar de hacerlo al llegar.

Comment: En España *buen provecho* es una expresión muy usual. Aquí, sin acortar al simple *provecho*

Comment: En Puerto Rico se dice buen provecho a las personas que están comiendo.

Answer (score 6):

En Chile se usa muy habitualmente. Casi siempre es "provecho" a secas, no "buen provecho". Yo estimo (esto no lo puedo confirmar) que es más frecuente en el estrato social bajo, y me parece que en zonas rurales puede ser incluso una falta de respeto no decirlo.

Si usted llega a un lugar en el que se está comiendo, aunque no conozca a las personas ahí presentes, se debe dirigir al grupo diciendo "provecho". Basta con que lo diga una de las personas que está llegando. Todos los comensales responden "gracias".

No se dice al retirarse, sino sólo al llegar.

Comment: Interesante. En España es común decirlo tanto al llegar como al irse: decimos un _que aproveche_ muy bajito bajando un poco la cabeza.